# How to access SMS Events?

Tags: events, windows-phone, sms, windows-phone-8.1

My company is looking to move from Android to Windows 8.1 phones but one of the obstacles we are seeing is that there are no Pager apps. We are looking into building our own but it looks like the Windows.Devices.Sms type methods are not available in Windows Phone 8.1. Is there a reference I can use to get the same functionality?

Comment: You cannot access text messages or call history in Windows Phone 8.1 as a result of security concerns. However you can send text messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way an app can access the text messages. Only in special cases, for example, **Truecaller** app alone has special permissions to intercept caller ID's. Since you say that you belong to an organization, you can approach Microsoft directly. They may give you special API's for that purpose.